# Apache2 rewrite(exclude) part of path

Tags: replace, url-rewriting, path, apache2, lang

I have a multy language site serverd by Apache2 webserver. Structure is

```
site.com - main version  
site.com/fr - for france  
site.com/it - another lang
```

I have a problem when i am trying to get static resources which are located in root direcory, like

```
site.com/js/bundle.js - right  
site.com/fr/js/bundle.js - wrong, because CMS sets base URL as site.com/fr
```

How can i strip language part from URL with .htaccess for static files img, js etc.
All languages are known.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ([\w]+)/([\w]+).\(js|css|vbs)$
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2.%3 [R,L]
```